# Customized SUSE Image not running in Google compute Engine

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine, suse

I have uploaded the customized image and created the VM instance of it. I am unable to do SSH in to it. As per troubleshooting guidelines I have attached the root persistent disk and from the log file I found that VM instance frequently booted and terminated from the log file "/var/log/messages". Please find the log file below

"

```
Nov 26 11:40:28 linux syslog-ng[1997]: syslog-ng starting up; version='2.0.9'
Nov 26 11:40:33 linux rchal: CPU frequency scaling is not supported by your processor.
Nov 26 11:40:33 linux rchal: boot with 'CPUFREQ=no' in to avoid this warning.
Nov 26 11:40:33 linux rchal: Cannot load cpufreq governors - No cpufreq driver available
Nov 26 11:40:33 linux kernel: klogd 1.4.1, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
Nov 26 11:40:33 linux kernel: [   18.645145] bootsplash: status on console 0 changed to on
Nov 26 11:40:57 linux kernel: [   57.972129] Uniform Multi-Platform E-IDE driver
Nov 26 11:40:57 linux kernel: [   57.988151] ide-cd driver 5.00
Nov 26 11:40:57 linux kernel: [   58.089061] st: Version 20101219, fixed bufsize 32768, s/g segs 256

Nov 26 11:41:02 linux kernel: [   62.944338] eth1: no IPv6 routers present
Nov 26 11:41:02 linux kernel: [   63.259092] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
Nov 26 17:11:16 linux su: (to root) root on none
Nov 26 17:11:26 linux SuSEfirewall2: Setting up rules from /etc/sysconfig/SuSEfirewall2 ...
Nov 26 17:11:27 linux SuSEfirewall2: using default zone 'ext' for interface eth1
Nov 26 17:11:27 linux kernel: [   88.008142] ip6_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
Nov 26 17:11:27 linux kernel: [   88.252544] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
Nov 26 17:11:27 linux kernel: [   88.296835] nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (7168 buckets, 28672 max)
Nov 26 17:11:28 linux SuSEfirewall2: batch committing...
Nov 26 17:11:29 linux SuSEfirewall2: Firewall rules successfully set
Nov 26 17:11:42 linux ifdown:     eth0      
Nov 26 17:11:44 linux ifdown:     eth1      
Nov 26 17:11:55 linux ifup:     lo        
Nov 26 17:11:55 linux ifup:     lo        
Nov 26 17:11:55 linux ifup: IP address: 127.0.0.1/8  
Nov 26 17:11:55 linux ifup:  
Nov 26 17:11:55 linux ifup:               
Nov 26 17:11:55 linux ifup: IP address: 127.0.0.2/8  
Nov 26 17:11:55 linux ifup:  
Nov 26 17:11:56 linux ifup:     eth0      
Nov 26 17:11:56 linux ifup:     eth0      
Nov 26 17:11:57 linux ifup: IP address: 10.203.92.100/24  
Nov 26 17:11:57 linux ifup:  
Nov 26 17:11:58 linux SuSEfirewall2: /var/lock/SuSEfirewall2.booting exists which means system boot in progress, exit.
Nov 26 17:11:59 linux ifup:     eth1      
Nov 26 17:11:59 linux ifup:     eth1      
Nov 26 17:11:59 linux ifup: IP address: 192.168.17.250/24  
Nov 26 17:11:59 linux ifup:  
Nov 26 17:12:01 linux SuSEfirewall2: /var/lock/SuSEfirewall2.booting exists which means system boot in progress, exit.
Nov 26 17:12:02 linux ifup:     tap0      
Nov 26 17:12:03 linux kernel: [  124.153528] tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
Nov 26 17:12:03 linux kernel: [  124.153528] tun: (C) 1999-2004 Max Krasnyansky <maxk@qualcomm.com>
Nov 26 17:12:03 linux kernel: [  124.219136] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): tap0: link is not ready
Nov 26 17:12:04 linux SuSEfirewall2: /var/lock/SuSEfirewall2.booting exists which means system boot in progress, exit.
Nov 26 17:12:04 linux SuSEfirewall2: Setting up rules from /etc/sysconfig/SuSEfirewall2 ...
Nov 26 17:12:04 linux SuSEfirewall2: using default zone 'ext' for interface eth1
Nov 26 17:12:06 linux SuSEfirewall2: batch committing...
Nov 26 17:12:06 linux SuSEfirewall2: Firewall rules successfully set
Nov 26 17:12:31 linux SuSEfirewall2: batch committing...
Nov 26 17:12:31 linux SuSEfirewall2: Firewall rules unloaded.
Nov 26 17:12:31 linux SuSEfirewall2: Setting up rules from /etc/sysconfig/SuSEfirewall2 ...
Nov 26 17:12:32 linux SuSEfirewall2: using default zone 'ext' for interface eth1
Nov 26 17:12:33 linux SuSEfirewall2: batch committing...
Nov 26 17:12:33 linux SuSEfirewall2: Firewall rules successfully set
Nov 26 17:12:39 linux init: Re-reading inittab
Nov 26 17:12:45 linux ifdown:     tap0      
Nov 26 17:12:48 linux ifdown:     eth0      
Nov 26 17:12:50 linux ifdown:     eth1      
Nov 26 17:12:55 linux init: Entering runlevel: 3
Nov 26 17:12:56 linux SuSEfirewall2: batch committing...
Nov 26 17:12:56 linux SuSEfirewall2: Firewall rules set to CLOSE.
Nov 26 17:12:57 linux kernel: Kernel logging (proc) stopped.
Nov 26 17:12:57 linux kernel: Kernel log daemon terminating.
Nov 26 17:12:57 linux syslog-ng[1997]: Termination requested via signal, terminating;
Nov 26 17:12:57 linux syslog-ng[1997]: syslog-ng shutting down; version='2.0.9'
Nov 26 17:12:57 deepak syslog-ng[8245]: syslog-ng starting up; version='2.0.9'
Nov 26 17:12:57 deepak firmware.sh[8273]: Cannot find  firmware file 'intel-ucode/06-17-0a'
Nov 26 17:13:02 deepak kernel: klogd 1.4.1, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
Nov 26 17:13:02 deepak kernel: [  178.548747] microcode: CPU0 sig=0x1067a, pf=0x40, revision=0x60b
Nov 26 17:13:02 deepak kernel: [  178.669173] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.00 <tigran@aivazian.fsnet.co.uk>, Peter Oruba
Nov 26 17:13:02 deepak kernel: [  178.824111] microcode: CPU0 update to revision 0xa0b failed
Nov 26 17:13:05 deepak ifup:     lo        
Nov 26 17:13:05 deepak ifup:     lo        
Nov 26 17:13:05 deepak ifup: IP address: 127.0.0.1/8  
Nov 26 17:13:05 deepak ifup:  
Nov 26 17:13:05 deepak ifup:               
Nov 26 17:13:06 deepak ifup: IP address: 127.0.0.2/8  
Nov 26 17:13:06 deepak ifup:  
Nov 26 17:13:07 deepak ifup:     eth0      
Nov 26 17:13:07 deepak ifup:     eth0      
Nov 26 17:13:07 deepak ifup: IP address: 10.203.92.100/24  
Nov 26 17:13:07 deepak ifup:  
Nov 26 17:13:08 deepak SuSEfirewall2: /var/lock/SuSEfirewall2.booting exists which means system boot in progress, exit.
Nov 26 17:13:09 deepak ifup:     eth1      
Nov 26 17:13:09 deepak ifup:     eth1      
Nov 26 17:13:09 deepak ifup: IP address: 192.168.17.250/24  
Nov 26 17:13:09 deepak ifup:  
Nov 26 17:13:10 deepak SuSEfirewall2: /var/lock/SuSEfirewall2.booting exists which means system boot in progress, exit.
Nov 26 17:13:16 deepak ifup:     tap0      
Nov 26 17:13:16 deepak kernel: [  197.436436] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): tap0: link is not ready
Nov 26 17:13:17 deepak SuSEfirewall2: /var/lock/SuSEfirewall2.booting exists which means system boot in progress, exit.
Nov 26 17:13:18 deepak auditd[9654]: Started dispatcher: /sbin/audispd pid: 9656
Nov 26 17:13:18 deepak kernel: [  199.072126] auditd (9654): /proc/9654/oom_adj is deprecated, please use /proc/9654/oom_score_adj instead.
Nov 26 17:13:18 deepak audispd: priority_boost_parser called with: 4
Nov 26 17:13:18 deepak audispd: af_unix plugin initialized
Nov 26 17:13:18 deepak audispd: audispd initialized with q_depth=80 and 1 active plugins
Nov 26 17:13:18 deepak auditd[9654]: Init complete, auditd 1.7.7 listening for events (startup state disable)
Nov 26 17:13:18 deepak haveged: haveged starting up
Nov 26 17:13:18 deepak haveged: arch:        x86 vendor:      intel generic:     0 i_cache:     32 d_cache:     32 loop_idx:    30 loop_idxmax: 40 loop_sz:     31836 loop_szmax:  124334 etime:       30361 havege_ndpt  0
Nov 26 17:13:19 deepak kernel: [  200.624132] BIOS EDD facility v0.16 2004-Jun-25, 1 devices found
Nov 26 17:13:20 deepak mcelog: mcelog read: No such device
Nov 26 17:21:10 deepak shadow[30512]: new group added - group=db2iadm1, gid=113, by=0
Nov 26 17:21:10 deepak shadow[30512]: running GROUPADD_CMD command - script=/usr/sbin/groupadd.local, account=db2iadm1, uid=113, gid=0, home=, by=0
Nov 26 17:21:11 deepak useradd[30526]: new account added - account=db2admin, uid=1005, gid=113, home=/home/db2admin, shell=/bin/bash, by=0
Nov 26 17:21:11 deepak useradd[30526]: account added to group - account=db2admin, group=video, gid=33, by=0
Nov 26 17:21:11 deepak useradd[30526]: account added to group - account=db2admin, group=dialout, gid=16, by=0
Nov 26 17:21:11 deepak useradd[30526]: home directory created - account=db2admin, uid=1005, home=/home/db2admin, by=0
Nov 26 17:21:11 deepak useradd[30526]: running USERADD_CMD command - script=/usr/sbin/useradd.local, account=db2admin, uid=1005, gid=113, home=/home/db2admin, by=0
Nov 26 17:21:11 deepak shadow[30530]: GID 113 is not unique - by=0
Nov 26 17:21:11 deepak shadow[30533]: new group added - group=db2fadm1, gid=114, by=0
Nov 26 17:21:11 deepak shadow[30533]: running GROUPADD_CMD command - script=/usr/sbin/groupadd.local, account=db2fadm1, uid=114, gid=0, home=, by=0
Nov 26 17:21:11 deepak useradd[30537]: new account added - account=db2fenc1, uid=1006, gid=114, home=/home/db2fenc1, shell=/bin/bash, by=0
Nov 26 17:21:11 deepak useradd[30537]: account added to group - account=db2fenc1, group=video, gid=33, by=0
Nov 26 17:21:11 deepak useradd[30537]: account added to group - account=db2fenc1, group=dialout, gid=16, by=0
Nov 26 17:21:11 deepak useradd[30537]: home directory created - account=db2fenc1, uid=1006, home=/home/db2fenc1, by=0
Nov 26 17:21:11 deepak useradd[30537]: running USERADD_CMD command - script=/usr/sbin/useradd.local, account=db2fenc1, uid=1006, gid=114, home=/home/db2fenc1, by=0
Nov 26 17:21:16 deepak su: (to db2admin) root on none
Nov 26 17:21:33 deepak su: (to db2admin) root on none
Nov 26 17:21:44 deepak su: (to db2admin) root on none
Nov 26 17:21:55 deepak su: (to db2admin) root on none
Nov 26 17:21:57 deepak su: (to db2admin) root on none
Nov 26 17:22:14 deepak su: (to db2admin) root on none
Nov 26 17:22:28 deepak su: (to db2admin) root on none
Nov 26 17:22:41 deepak su: (to db2admin) root on none
Nov 26 17:22:55 deepak su: (to db2admin) root on none
Nov 26 17:23:08 deepak su: (to db2admin) root on none
Nov 26 17:23:22 deepak su: (to db2admin) root on none
Nov 26 17:23:35 deepak su: (to db2admin) root on none
Nov 26 17:23:49 deepak su: (to db2admin) root on none
Nov 26 17:24:02 deepak su: (to db2admin) root on none
Nov 26 17:24:16 deepak su: (to db2admin) root on none
Nov 26 17:24:30 deepak su: (to db2admin) root on none
Nov 26 17:24:45 deepak su: (to db2admin) root on none
Nov 26 17:25:12 deepak su: (to db2admin) root on none
Nov 26 17:27:32 deepak su: (to db2admin) root on none
Nov 26 17:27:40 deepak su: (to db2admin) root on none
Nov 26 17:27:49 deepak su: (to db2admin) root on none
Nov 26 17:31:35 deepak su: (to db2admin) root on none
Nov 26 17:32:11 deepak auditd[9654]: The audit daemon is exiting.
Nov 26 17:32:12 deepak auditd[22290]: Started dispatcher: /sbin/audispd pid: 22292
Nov 26 17:32:12 deepak audispd: priority_boost_parser called with: 4
Nov 26 17:32:12 deepak audispd: af_unix plugin initialized
Nov 26 17:32:12 deepak audispd: audispd initialized with q_depth=80 and 1 active plugins
Nov 26 17:32:12 deepak auditd[22290]: Init complete, auditd 1.7.7 listening for events (startup state disable)
Nov 26 17:32:12 deepak shadow[22299]: group already exists - group=ns_admin, by=0
Nov 26 17:32:12 deepak shadow[22302]: account removed from group - account=sas, group=users, gid=100, by=0
Nov 26 17:32:12 deepak shadow[22302]: account removed from group - account=sas, group=ns_admin, gid=36, by=0
Nov 26 17:32:12 deepak shadow[22309]: account removed from group - account=mani, group=users, gid=100, by=0
Nov 26 17:32:12 deepak shadow[22309]: account removed from group - account=mani, group=ns_admin, gid=36, by=0
Nov 26 17:32:13 deepak shadow[22310]: account removed from group - account=vivek, group=users, gid=100, by=0
Nov 26 17:32:13 deepak shadow[22310]: account removed from group - account=vivek, group=ns_admin, gid=36, by=0
Nov 26 17:32:16 deepak sshd[22356]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 4422.
Nov 26 17:32:16 deepak sshd[22356]: Server listening on :: port 4422.
Nov 26 17:32:16 deepak /usr/sbin/cron[22393]: (CRON) STARTUP (V5.0)
Nov 26 17:32:17 deepak smartd[22406]: smartd 5.39 2008-10-24 22:33 [x86_64-suse-linux-gnu] (openSUSE RPM) Copyright (C) 2002-8 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net
Nov 26 17:32:17 deepak smartd[22406]: Opened configuration file /etc/smartd.conf
Nov 26 17:32:17 deepak smartd[22406]: Drive: DEVICESCAN, implied '-a' Directive on line 26 of file /etc/smartd.conf
Nov 26 17:32:17 deepak smartd[22406]: Configuration file /etc/smartd.conf was parsed, found DEVICESCAN, scanning devices
Nov 26 17:32:17 deepak smartd[22406]: Device: /dev/sda, type changed from 'scsi' to 'sat'
Nov 26 17:32:17 deepak smartd[22406]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], opened
Nov 26 17:32:17 deepak smartd[22406]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], not found in smartd database.
Nov 26 17:32:17 deepak smartd[22406]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], lacks SMART capability
Nov 26 17:32:17 deepak smartd[22406]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], to proceed anyway, use '-T permissive' Directive.
Nov 26 17:32:17 deepak smartd[22406]: Unable to monitor any SMART enabled devices. Try debug (-d) option. Exiting...
Nov 26 17:32:18 deepak SuSEfirewall2: Setting up rules from /etc/sysconfig/SuSEfirewall2 ...
Nov 26 17:32:18 deepak SuSEfirewall2: using default zone 'ext' for interface eth1
Nov 26 17:32:20 deepak SuSEfirewall2: batch committing...
Nov 26 17:32:21 deepak SuSEfirewall2: Firewall rules successfully set
Nov 26 17:33:14 deepak shutdown[22325]: shutting down for system reboot
Nov 26 17:33:14 deepak init: Switching to runlevel: 6
Nov 26 17:33:21 deepak kernel: [ 1401.996463] bootsplash: status on console 0 changed to on
Nov 26 17:33:24 deepak sshd[22356]: Received signal 15; terminating.
Nov 26 17:33:25 deepak auditd[22290]: The audit daemon is exiting.
Nov 26 17:33:25 deepak haveged: haveged stopping due to signal 15
Nov 26 17:33:26 deepak su: (to db2admin) root on /dev/console
Nov 26 17:33:45 deepak kernel: Kernel logging (proc) stopped.
Nov 26 17:33:45 deepak kernel: Kernel log daemon terminating.
Nov 26 17:33:45 deepak syslog-ng[8245]: Termination requested via signal, terminating;
Nov 26 17:33:45 deepak syslog-ng[8245]: syslog-ng shutting down; version='2.0.9'
Nov 26 17:34:51 deepak syslog-ng[1137]: syslog-ng starting up; version='2.0.9'
Nov 26 17:34:52 deepak firmware.sh[1165]: Cannot find  firmware file 'intel-ucode/06-17-0a'
Nov 26 17:34:53 deepak rchal: CPU frequency scaling is not supported by your processor."
```

If Someone has any idea from the log about why it is happening or how to resolve please comment out.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [instance serial port output](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/get-serial-port-output)  to find more about [debug messages from your instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting#pdboot).

The fact that the instances is being rebooted and terminated will not allow you to SSH. There are suggestions at this link for the error "[CPU frequency scaling is not supported by your processor](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/421215-OpenSuse-11-1-and-Multiple-Processors)"